# MATLAB: How to share a HashMap in parallel computing

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

**Setup**

I am trying to parallelize an algorithm that runs the same code on each row of a matrix (and then postprocesses the results.)

There are some computations that occur in the processing of multiple rows (this reoccurence is hard to predict).

Therefore, currently I call an object that performs these computations and saves the results in a HashMap, so when processing row $n$ needs computations that were already done for row $m$ they don't need to be done again.

It does not affect the outcome of the algorithm in which order the rows are processed.

**Problem**

I am not able to use the HashMap in parallel code, each worker ends up with its own HashMap.

I understand the philosophy behind this behavior. Yet in my example, order does not matter and I would like to circumvent the standard behavior.

**Minimal working example**

```
classdef MyPar <handle
    properties
        map;
    end
    methods 
        function obj=MyPar()
            obj.map=containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','any');
        end
        function y=compute(obj,n)
           if ~obj.map.isKey(n)
               obj.map(n)=sin(n);
               fprintf('Did not find key ''%d''\n',n)
           else
               fprintf('Found key ''%d''\n',n)
           end
           y=obj.map(n);
        end
    end
    methods(Static)
        function R=test()
            c=MyPar();
            Nworkers=3;
            A=ones(Nworkers,2);
            spmd(Nworkers)
               R=c.compute(A(labindex,1))+c.compute(A(labindex,2));
            end    
        end
    end
end
```

Running MyPar.test() gives

```
>> MyPar.test();
Lab 1: 
  Did not find key '1'
  Found key '1'
Lab 2: 
  Did not find key '1'
  Found key '1'
Lab 3: 
  Did not find key '1'
  Found key '1'
```

In this trivial example, I would wish to have a code where two of the three workers don't need to do their own computations at all (because the only computation ever done is `compute(1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's parallel computing does not quite work this way - iterations are independent from one another. You could theoretically communicate data back and forth between workers via e.g. sockets (good example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31673-parfor-progress-monitor-v2)), but this is probably an overkill for your task, and added overhead may even outweigh the benefit.

Have you considered splitting your logic into several parts? Using your simple example, you could first find a unique set of matrix elements that you need to perform computations on. Run through all these computations in a `parfor` loop, saving results into a simple array, or a cell array (if the result of each iteration is something else than a single number). You can then apply the rest of your logic to these results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion is technically possible I am sure. I just couldn't find the motivation to abandon my running code not knowing that it's impossible what I want.  You are right though, I don't even know what sockets are,  so doing some preprocessing will be the simplest solution